# Magento 2: Admin Speed

Tags: magento2

We are building our first M2 site. We noticed that the administration area is running slower than we would expect. This especially causes headaches when trying to create the product catalog. The difference between a 2 second product search, view or edit and a 6-8 second can make catalog management quite a grind.

Just to make sure, I had reasonable expectations, I set out to find some 'demo' Mage 2 implementations for comparison. I found 3 accessible admin interfaces for demo installations.

I ran the several tests on both our test installation and the demos that we found. The results are as follows:

- **Admin dashboard load:** 2-3 seconds
- **Admin products catalog list load:** 5-6 seconds
- **Admin product load (configurable):** 6-9 seconds
- **Admin product save (configurable, including reloading it following):** 9-12 seconds
- **Admin order listing load:** 4-6 seconds
- **Admin order load:** 3-6 seconds

Most of these tests (including our internal test) were on a basic LUMA install with the preset products/orders provided in the seed data.

Before testing, I completed the following optimisations on my test installation:

- All caches, indexes on
- Production mode on
- Redis configured
- Logging off
- PHP7 used
- Enabled flat categories and products
- Removed all extensions
- Turned on Varnish
- Set up memcache

Two questions:

1. Are my findings on par with expectations? If not, how long should I expect these tests to take if I have a well optimized installation?
2. What suggestions do you have to optimize admin performance beyond what I have already performed?

Answer (score 1):

1. Try re-indexing all the indices and make sure you have proper permissions for your pub/static and var/ folders.
2. Make sure your Redis cache is configured properly.

Answer (score 0):

First, I have the same problem. And I do not like it at all. I can optimize the front end but the back end is very slow.

Three things that seemed to help :

1. Turning on Opcache and FPM for PHP on our server
2. I don't know what this is exactly - but we moved from "worker" to "event" for Apache
3. I set the php memory limit to 4000MB

It changed admin performance from what was like 3 deep breaths to two deep breaths.

I was considering going to lightspeed and litemage - but I dont think it will do anything substantial.

I am moving our cart from something else to magento 2.1 and I am afraid that people will not let me move because the order processing will suck.